# Set value based on if other variable is in specific range

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, cp-sat

I have the following problem.

`number_of_machines` is controlled by other constraints. I need to set line variable to specific value based on "range" constraint.

```
number_of_machines = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, '')

model.Add(line == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(number_of_machines > 5 and number_of_machines <= 10)
model.Add(line == 6).OnlyEnforceIf(number_of_machines >= 11 and number_of_machines <= 20)
model.Add(line == 2).OnlyEnforceIf(number_of_machines >= 21 and number_of_machines <= 50)
model.Add(line == 8).OnlyEnforceIf(number_of_machines >= 51 and number_of_machines <= 100)
```

for "AND" I'm getting the error: NotImplementedError: Evaluating a LinearExpr instance as a Boolean is not implemented.
And for linear expression I'm getting another error: 'BoundedLinearExpression' object has no attribute 'Index'

Could you help me with how I should set such conditions in the CP-SAT model?

UPDATED: fixed directions of comparisons (as noticed in the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md

`OnlyEnforceIf()` only accept one or more Boolean literals.

So for the first constraint (assuming there is an error in the direction of the comparisons):

```
b1 = model.NewBoolVar()
model.AddLinearConstraint(number_of_machines, 6, 10).OnlyEnforceIf(b1)
model.Add(line == 8).OnlyEnforceIf(b1)
```

and most likely in the end

```
model.Add(sum(bi) == 1)
```

Comment: thank you very much!, that should work!! I read this guide, and I was already thinking of using AddImplication, but didn't understand that I should not control b1 directly, the model will pick the only one by itself!